# How to create a LXC container without rootfs

Tags: lxc

I want to create a container without "rootfs" in lxc 1.0.5 and Ubuntu 14.04.

I did it before in previous versions of lxc. In previous versions if we use lxc-create without "-t" option, it will create a container without "rootfs".

so I try:

```
lxc-create -n foo
```

and i got this error:

```
lxc_container: Error creating container foo
```

I read new lxc-create manpage. The new [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/lxc-create.1.html) say:

> ```
>        -t template
>               'template' is the short name of an existing 'lxc-template'
>               script that is called by lxc-create, eg. busybox, debian,
>               fedora, ubuntu or sshd.  Refer to the examples in
>               /usr/local/share/lxc/templates for details of the expected
>               script structure.  Alternatively, the full path to an
>               executable template script can also be passed as a parameter.
>               "none" can be used to force lxc-create to skip rootfs
>               creation.
> ```

I try it:

```
lxc-create -n foo -t none
```

and i get error again:

```
lxc_container: No such file or directory - bad template: none
lxc_container: bad template: none
lxc_container: Error creating container foo
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't you hate it when reality changes, but the documentation doesn't?

Try using -t /bin/true